# Write results in text file

Tags: c#, .net

I want to write the result of var item in text file.
I use File.WriteAllText, the path is @"C:\Users\TBM\Desktop\test.txt"
but I only get the last value of item, which is EDC

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var alphabet = "ABCDE";
    var q = alphabet.Select(x => x.ToString());
    int size = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        q = q.SelectMany(x => alphabet, (x, y) => x + y);
    }

    foreach (var item in q)
    {
        if ((item[0] == item[1]) || (item[1] == item[2]) || (item[0] == item[2]))
        {
            continue;
             File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\TBM\Desktop\test.txt", item);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StreamWriter` is the easiest way to write to a text file while you're looping through something:

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
{
    foreach (something in somethingElse)
    {
        string line = "compute this line somehow";
        sw.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

That's all you need - your file will be created, written, saved, and closed.

Comment: This is also the best way to avoid using too much memory - any time you do `File.WriteAllText` or `File.WriteAllLines` or any of those, you'd need the entire contents in memory in a string or string array. With `StreamWriter`, like other Stream-based IO in .NET, you can write a little bit at a time without hogging up memory, so it's really the only way to deal with a large file.

Answer (score 0):

`File.WriteAllText()` opens the file, writes your text to it then closes the file. You need to lookup one of the many examples of writing a text file line by line.

Answer (score 0):

`WriteAllText` Overrites the entire contents of the text file with that item.  The smallest change would be to change your code to use `AppendAllText` instead (clearing the file before the loop if that's what you want), but the more idomatic solution is to refactor your code to use `WriteAllLines`:

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, q);
```

That will simply write each item out on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

Your File.WriteAllText() call in your example comes after continue -- how does it ever get invoked? It needs to be outside your if brackets.

Answer (score 0):

should it be

```
foreach (var item in q)
{
    if ((item[0] == item[1]) || (item[1] == item[2]) || (item[0] == item[2]))
    {
        continue;

    }
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\TBM\Desktop\test.txt", item);

}
```

Doesn't continue keyword skip the rest of the loop body?